# pgadmin4 command throws sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError

Tags: python, linux, sqlalchemy, pgadmin-4

I am on Debian Linux and  already had pgadmin4 installed. I recently upgraded the os and since then I never used. Now, if I attempt to start

```
 pgadmin4
```

It gives me this error:

```
 File "/usr/local/bin/pgadmin4", line 5, in <module>
    from pgadmin4.pgAdmin4 import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 418, in create_app
    upgrade_db()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 385, in upgrade_db
    is_db_error, invalid_tb_names = check_db_tables()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/setup/db_table_check.py", line 25, in check_db_tables
    if not db.engine.dialect.has_table(db.engine, table_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py", line 2009, in has_table
    self._ensure_has_table_connection(connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 341, in _ensure_has_table_connection
    raise exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: The argument passed to Dialect.has_table() should be a <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection'>, got <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>. Additionally, the Dialect.has_table() method is for internal dialect use only; please use ``inspect(some_engine).has_table(<tablename>>)`` for public API use.
```

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Comment: What version of SQLA you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

I had pgadmin4 globally installed `sudo apt install pgadmin4`. Since there is an issue with the latest version of package, I decided to install with python (always life saver). I could change the package versions globally but this would break other apps. Better way is to have `pgadmin4` in its own container with compatible packages:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/pgadmin
$ sudo mkdir /var/log/pgadmin
$ sudo chown $USER /var/lib/pgadmin
$ cd
$ python3 -m venv pgadmin4
$ source pgadmin4/bin/activate
(pgadmin4) $ pip install pgadmin4
```

Now I had to install compatible versions of the packages inside virtual environment:

```
 sudo pip install "SQLAlchemy==1.3.8"
 sudo pip install "Flask==1.1.0"
```